# Flexbox evenly spacing elements and wrapping on narrower screens

Tags: html, css, flexbox

On wide screens, I'd like to present two divs evenly spaced like this:

```
|          [ONE]             [TWO]            |
```

When the width of the screen is less than the combined widths of the divs, I'd like them to wrap and each be centered like this:

```
|  [ONE]  |
|  [TWO]  |
```

I'm currently trying to do this with flexbox like this:

```
.evenly-space {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

<div class="evenly-space">
  <div style="width:200px;border:1px solid black">ONE</div>
  <div style="width:200px;border:1px solid black">TWO</div>
</div>
```

But the two elements stay on one line and don't wrap.

Is there a way to accomplish this with flexbox or another way?

Comment: Did you tried `flex-wrap: wrap`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `flex-wrap: wrap`

```css
.evenly-space {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="evenly-space">
  <div style="width:200px;border:1px solid black">ONE</div>
  <div style="width:200px;border:1px solid black">TWO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the quick answer!

Answer (score 3):

You have to add and set the `flex-wrap` property to `wrap`

```
.evenly-space {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to add

```
 flex-wrap: wrap;
```

property in your `.evenly-space` class